# Form transition not showing correctly for Uncover

Tags: animation, codenameone

I have 2 forms I will call **formA** and **formB**.

**formA** contains a button that opens **formB** and I called `formA.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createCover(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, false, 300));` before showing **formB**. **formB** slides over **formA** from the bottom as expected.

On **formB**, I have an X button and I want it to reverse the above transition by sliding back **formB** to reveal **formA**. In this case, I called `formB.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createUncover(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, false, 300));` which gave me wrong undesirable transition.

It performs almost the same operation as `createCover()` except that the screen flickers.

Is this how Uncover suppose to work? or is there another way of achieving my illustration above?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug here. It should be fixed with the next update. Thanks.

Uncover should indeed be the exact opposite of cover and it looks to me that your usage is correct.